# How do I compare two array Objects - Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumerate

I have 2 Array of type `[Any]` - objects of dictionaries
And other array contains other set of objects `[Any]` (2nd array objects are contains in first array)

I need to find the index of the first array of second array elements

eg: -

```
let firstArray = [["key1":6],["key2":8],["key3":64],["key4":68],["key5":26],["key6":76]]

let secondArray = [["key3":64],["key6":68]]
```

How can I find the `firstArray` index of `secondArray` elements

Comment: Are you saying that you want find the entire second array as a sub-array of the first array?  Your question isn't clear

Comment: @DuncanC: exactly. second array elements are contains in the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let index = firstArray.index{$0 == secondArray[0]};
print("this value ", index);
```

will print optional(2) , it is basically 2

Comment: It might be better to use the `Array.index(where:)` of the method so it's clear what you're doing. Using trailing closure syntax makes it hard for readers to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

First, you take the **keys** from your `secondArray`. Then, you try to find the **index** of key in your `firstArray`. Be aware that some values might be nil if the key doesn't exist.

```
let firstArray = [["key1":6],["key2":8],["key3":64],["key4":68],["key5":26],["key6":76]]
let secondArray = [["key3":64],["key6":68], ["key8": 100]]

let indexes = secondArray
    .map({ $0.first?.key }) //map the values to the keys
    .map({ secondKey -> Int? in
        return firstArray.index(where:
            { $0.first?.key == secondKey } //compare the key from your secondArray to the ones in firstArray
        )
    })

print(indexes) //[Optional(2), Optional(5), nil]
```

I also added an example case where the result is nil.